# Error: CMake giving a linking error when all definitions are provided

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile a program with CMake, which is new to me, and it sucessfuly builds but fails in the linking stage. I have everything defined, so I'm not sure why it's failing.

Here's the relevent code

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "file_management.hpp"
#include "data_retrieval.hpp"
#include "data_writing.hpp"

using namespace std; // namespace std;


int main(){
    map<string ,string> package_map;

    map<string ,string> map;

    map["abc"] = "123";
    map["luv"] = "123";
    map["you"] = "self";

    {//outputting to testfile
    ofstream testfile{"doc/testfile.txt"};
    check_open(testfile);
    deposit_map(map, testfile);

    testfile.close();
    }

    ifstream testfile{"doc/testfile.txt"};
    check_open(testfile);
    retrieve_map(package_map, testfile);

    for (const auto& item : package_map){
        cout << item.first << '\t' << item.second << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is coming from `deposit_map` in `"data_writing.cpp"`, so here's the header and source files for `data_writing.cpp`:

header

```
#ifndef DATA_WRITING
    #define DATA_WRITING

    template <typename T>
    void deposit_vector(std::vector<T> source_vector, std::ofstream& output_file);
        
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    void deposit_map(std::map<T1,T2> source_map, std::ofstream& output_file);

#endif
```

source

```
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include "file_management.hpp"

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void deposit_map(std::map<T1,T2> source_map, std::ofstream& output_file){
    for( const auto& item : source_map){
        output_file << item.first << '\t' << item.second << '\n';
    }
}

template <typename T>
void deposit_vector(std::vector<T> source_vector, std::ofstream& output_file){
    for( const auto& x : source_vector){
        output_file << x << '\n';
    }
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Post_Transition CXX)
add_executable(Ptran
                data_retrieval.cpp
                data_writing.cpp
                file_management.cpp
                main.cpp
                package.cpp)
```

And finally, here's the error:

```
CMakeFiles\Ptran.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x1d4): undefined reference to `void deposit_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
```

I've looked up sections of the error, and based on other posts on here it looks like it is a linking error. All solutions I found were very complex, and had to deal with reordering libraries and "glob", which I'm unsure of what that meant at all. But I feel like I must be doing something wrong, because this seems like a relatively simple task, and CMake is definitely capable of compiling and linking five files.

Comment: This is a nice question, with good [mcve] (`main()` could be shortened a bit, but it's not bad as is), you did research before asking - well done! However, it's still a duplicate, so I closed it. The TL;DR version - you can't split template definition into header and source file, it must all be in the header. Longer explanation is in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank you so much, I had no idea you couldn't put templates in the .cpp, and I don't how long it would have taken me to figure out what the problem was.

Comment: It's a very common gotcha in C++. Unfortunately, this is how the language works, so it's a "everyone has to get through it" situation.